# Get GraphicsMagick to open file from a https url?

Tags: https, graphicsmagick

I can use GraphicsMagick to download images given a URL, however when the URL starts with a https I get the following error (for https://example.com/image.png):

```
Unable to open file (//example.com/image.png) [No such file or directory].
```

I am using the `gm` driver for node.js with code like so:

```
gm = require('gm');
gm(url).write(name);
```

but have also tried the `gm` directly from the command line with the same issue.

As stated already, it works fine for http URLS, can I get it to work for https?

Answer (score 3):

GraphicsMagick uses the HTTP support from libxml2, which does not currently support HTTPS.  Try using an external program like 'wget' or 'curl' (which use OpenSSL to support HTTPS) to retrieve the file.  Then you can pass the returned file to GraphicsMagick.

Answer (score 2):

As Bob said, HTTPS is still not supported BUT:

Using the https module you can create a buffer and input it directly into GraphicsMagick.

```
https.get('https://www.eff.org/files/https-everywhere2.jpg', function(response) {

    gm(response, 'image.jpg')
        .write('test.jpg', function(err) {
            if (err) return handle(err);
            console.log('Created an image from a Buffer!');
        });
});
```

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work. I'm trying to resize the image. But it's not piping anything. I'm doing something like `gm(response).resize(x,y).stream().pipe(someStream)`. Any thoughts?