# Node.js serverless getting img width from URL

Tags: node.js, sharp

I`m currently running a Google Cloud Function and am trying to get the width of an image given a remote URL. I am having trouble doing this. I have tried fetching the data using axios, but I do not know what to do with the data. I have tried using GraphicsMagick and Sharp but both seem to have issues taking in remote URLs. GraphicsMagick in particular seems to be incompatible with Cloud Functions

This is the code I currently have:

```
let res = await axios({ url: url, method: "get", timeout: 8000 });
let imgData = Buffer.from(res.data, "binary").toString("base64")
const imgInfo = await sharp(imgData).toBuffer();
```

Sharp error:

```
[Error: Input file contains unsupported image format]
```

It's not a lot, but I haven't been able to get either gm or sharp to work successfully. If you know of a better way to get the height/width of an image please let me know.

**Solution**
Going further into the solution below, what I did was this:

```
        let data = await checkUrl(images[i].attrs.src, url);
        let imgBuffer = Buffer.from(data, "binary");
        let imgBufferInfo = await sharp(imgBuffer)
          .metadata()
          .then(function (metadata) {
            return metadata;
          })
          .catch(function (err) {
            return err;
          });
        console.log("imgBuffer: " + imgBufferInfo.width);
```

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/a/30419468/3284355 ?

Comment: @Molda Unfortunately graphicsMagick is not possible to install on Cloud Functions as far as I can tell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the module and ran it. https://github.com/lovell/sharp

The input value of the `Sharp` object created according to the input is different.
When executing a buffer as an input, data is stored in the `buffer` of the `input`, and when executing a Base64 text as an input, the data is stored in a `file` of the `input`.

---

In the case of toBuffer(), the `input(buffer)` can be interpreted, but the `input(file)` format cannot be interpreted.

I don't know what you want, but you need the just `toBuffer()` action, create the input as a buffer and use it.

---

here are example code & logs

```js
const fs = require('fs')
const sharp = require('sharp')

fs.readFile('profile.png', async (err, data) => {
    let imgBuffer = Buffer.from(data, 'binary');
    let imgBase64 = imgBuffer.toString('base64');

    const imgBufferInfo = await sharp(imgBuffer);
    console.log(imgBufferInfo); // --- [1]

    const imgBase64Info = await sharp(imgBase64);
    console.log(imgBase64Info); // --- [2]

    const result = await imgBufferInfo.toBuffer();
    console.log(result);
    // <Buffer 89 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a 0a 00 00 00 0d 49 48 44 52 00 00 01 3f 00 00 01 23 08 02 00 00 00 cb d0 91 1c 00 00 00 09 70 48 59 73 00 00 0b 36 00 00 0b 36 01 ... 159137 more bytes>

    console.log(imgBuffer);
    // <Buffer 89 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a 0a 00 00 00 0d 49 48 44 52 00 00 01 3f 00 00 01 23 08 02 00 00 00 cb d0 91 1c 00 00 00 09 70 48 59 73 00 00 0b 36 00 00 0b 36 01 ... 159137 more bytes>
});
```

---

[1] imgBufferInfo Sharp object

```
Sharp {
  ...
  options: {
    ...
    input: {
      failOnError: true,
      limitInputPixels: 268402689,
      sequentialRead: false,
      buffer: <Buffer 89 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a 0a 00 00 00 0d 49 48 44 52 00 00 01 3f 00 00 01 23 08 02 00 00 00 cb d0 91 1c 00 00 00 09 70 48 59 73 00 00 0b 36 00 00 0b 36 01 ... 123176 more bytes>
    }
  }
}
```

---

[2] imgBase64Info Sharp object

```
Sharp {
  ...
  options: {
    ...
    input: {
      failOnError: true,
      limitInputPixels: 268402689,
      sequentialRead: false,
      file: 'iVBORw0KGg...5ErkJggg=='
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Any idea on how can I convert that buffer into file and return it back to user without saving it in server's diskStorage